# Add custom class to main blade template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My `app.blade.php` file is my main file that will `@yield` all my other blade template files. I noticed that the `Auth` class is available to this file. I cant figure out how to add one of my custom classes, `Projects` so it is available to `app.blade.php`.

`app.blade.php` contains a drop down menu where I need to list all my projects, but if I try something like

```
Projects::where('user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)->get()
```

I get an error saying the Projects class is not found. How can I add this to my master template just like how `Auth` is available? Or, do I need to go about this differently?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do it by injecting the class into your template.

```
@inject('project', 'App\Project')

{{ $project->where('user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)->get() }}
```

Just make sure your namespace is correct.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#service-injection

Comment: how easy, that worked! How is the `Auth` service available without injecting? I'll accept your answer in a few mins when SO allows me

Comment: I haven't really looked into that so I'm not sure but my guess is something to do with namespaces.

Comment: gotcha..well if anyone knows the answer, please share!

Comment: @Ronnie You can do via a view composer. http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views#view-composers